# Google Sheets ImportXML to extract image URL from Amazon Product

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to retrieve the Image URL of an amazon product link. I need the image URL in a Google Sheet. I used the IMPORTXML function to get the Product name and price, but I can't get it to work with the image, especially because I need the URL.

I am an absolute beginner and basically just use no code apps, so I don't have a lot of experience unfortunately.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to retrieve an image URL is to simply right-click the image and choose "Copy image address", which will copy the image URL to your clipboard. Then just click inside the cell of Google Sheets where you want it and hit Ctrl-V to paste that URL.

Or if you feel you want to verify the image URL first, you can r-click the image and then choose "Open image in new tab." The URL showing in that new tab above the full image is the image URL. Just copy it from there and paste it into Google Sheets.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I guess I wasn’t totally clear about the use case. The Amazon URL is posted into a Google sheet via Zapier, the Metadata like the product name, price and image URL should then be filled automatically. 

Use case: I have build a „no Code“ App which relies on a Google sheet as a database. In this App the users can paste an Amazon link and „import“ the product into their profile. This import should include the image URL and should be populated automatically via a function within sheets. Or via something happening in Zapier or Integromat for that matter.

Comment: Amazon doesn't make it easy for you to do this. Even the right-click method only works on some products (like books). Most product pages have multiple images which are displayed via JS, not in the HTML itself; so there is no XPATH to them.